# Why Dumping a .NET Process Increases Memory Usage

Tags: .net, memory, dump, memory-dump

We have a .NET service using ~30MB of memory at startup. (VM ~= Mem usage)
I wanted to dump the process and find out what is holding those 30MB.

The CDB debugger generating the mini-dump **increased mem usage by 100MB**.
From the dump I could see those 100MB were image memory (DLLs)

> ```
> -------------------- Usage SUMMARY --------------------------
>     TotSize (      KB)   Pct(Tots) Pct(Busy)   Usage
>     2d07000 (   46108) : 02.20%    28.45%    : RegionUsageIsVAD
>    761ac000 ( 1935024) : 92.27%    00.00%    : RegionUsageFree
>     64b0000 (  103104) : 04.92%    63.62%    : RegionUsageImage
>      900000 (    9216) : 00.44%    05.69%    : RegionUsageStack
>        9000 (      36) : 00.00%    00.02%    : RegionUsageTeb
>      380000 (    3584) : 00.17%    02.21%    : RegionUsageHeap
>           0 (       0) : 00.00%    00.00%    : RegionUsagePageHeap
>        1000 (       4) : 00.00%    00.00%    : RegionUsagePeb
>        1000 (       4) : 00.00%    00.00%    : RegionUsageProcessParametrs
>        2000 (       8) : 00.00%    00.00%    : RegionUsageEnvironmentBlock
>        Tot: 7fff0000 (2097088 KB) Busy: 09e44000 (162064 KB)
> ```

The mem usage is left high, long after the debugger detached.
I want to know what is casing this image load / memory raise?

Thanks.

Comment: Not really surprising. .NET has a lot of overhead.  Better to write system-level code in C or C++ which has less overhead.

Comment: @John .NET's overhead isn't as big as is assumed.  The memory manager is tuned for performance, not footprint.

Comment: @NET fanbois you can stop flagging John's comment.  Jeez, you flaggers are making us .NET developers look as bad as PHP devs *ducks and covers*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Typically, unused pages are not part of the working set, just of the address 
space. When you are creating a full dump, all the pages in the address space
are read-in, and written to disk. As long as the size of the dump is basically equivalent to the size of the address space of the process, what you describe is expected."

I got the answer from [Ivan Brugiolo & Pavel Lebedinsky](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.windbg/browse_thread/thread/5b6f565bb24d87a4/ebcecc222328f92a?show_docid=ebcecc222328f92a).

Answer (score -1):

You can use a profiler to analyze the memory consumption.

1. [NProfiler](http://chimpswithkeyboards.com/projects/nprofiler/) - foss
2. [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/) - not free

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I really love using Windbg / SOS / CLRProfiler.I know where memory is consumed, I just wanted to learn why dumping the process loads all DLL’s...

Comment: It think it's because the dump takes all the loaded CLR with it. But i'm not sure.